# Click Event in 'Backbone.js View' do not work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I tried to start to work with backbone.js, but I found the Event does not work when I do NOT use 'body' as the View's el.
Here is the code. You can save it as a html file and run it.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <button id='openEssay'>test</button>
        <div id='div' style='width:100px;height:100px;'></div><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.6/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script><script>
    (function($){
        var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

            el:'body',//success
    //fail  el:'#div',
    //fail    tagName: 'li',
    //fail    id:'div',
            initialize:function(){
                _.bindAll(this, 'openEssay');
            },
            events:{
                'click button#openEssay':'openEssay'
            },
            openEssay:function(){
                alert('a');
            }
       });
       var app = new AppView();
    })(jQuery);

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Those elements do not exist on your page.

Comment: oh!!!!plz remove 'this.$el.appendTo('body'); ', the DEMO do not need this line

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Backbone binds the event handlers to the view's `this.el` using the delegation form of [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (or [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in older Backbones), see [`Backbone.View#delegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) for details. So if you want these events:

```
events: {
    'click button#openEssay':'openEssay'
}
```

to do anything then `this.$el.find('button#openEssay')` needs to match something (where `this` is, of course, the view object). Only one of your four attempts:

1. `el: 'body'`
2. `el:'#div'`
3. `tagName: 'li'`
4. `id: 'div'`

will put `<button id="openEssay">` inside `this.el` so only **(1)** will call `openEssay` when you hit the button. If you put your button inside `#div` then **(2)** would also work.

Comment: Good Answer.. Many Thanks Bro

Answer (score 0):

the answer above was very helpfull to me, especially when it comes to modularization, in my case i'm trying to build a specie of View component to be used in anyone view. But the part of events always does nothing, to fix that, i just put in my component view el: 'body',  too easy

```js
var RoleView = BaseView.extend({
  el: 'body',
  template : doT.template(RoleTemplate),
  model : new SessionModel(),
  events: {
   "click #open-RoleModal" : "_OpenRoleModal",
            "click #normal-Role": "_makeRole"
        },
  initialize:function(options){
   BaseView.prototype.initialize.call(this,options);
  },
  _OpenRoleModal: function(){
          //it works
  },
        _makeRole : function() {
          //it works
        },
        close: function(){
            this.$el.empty().off();
        }

 });
```