# Backbone delegateEvents not bubbling / propagating

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, event-propagation

Weird problem with event propagation in Backbone. Most people ask how to stop event propagation, but I'm struggling with getting my events to propagate!!

Here I have two View objects. The MainView which contains Item views and listens to click events to call run():

```
var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...

    events: {
        "click .item": "run" // works only if no click event in Item
    },

    render: {
         // Item View object children
    },

    run: function() {
        //run :)
    }
});
```

Item view objects also listen to click events on themselves to toggle on/off behaviour:

```
var Item = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...

    events: {
        "click" : "toggle" // MainView click event works when this is removed
    },

    toggle: function() {
        this.model.toggle();
    }
});
```

The problem being that MainView.run() is not fired when the Item is clicked, while it has a click event for Item.toggle().

However, MainView.run() **DOES** fire if I remove the Item.toggle() click event. Leading me to the conclusion that the event is somehow forced to stop propagating, outside of my control.

How can I solve this problem? Am I missing something obvious, or is this unavoidable?

Thank you for any and all suggestions and answers :).

Comment: Seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/nMuE9/

Comment: That should not be a problem at all. Difficult to say what exactly is happening unless you jot up your whole code

Comment: Your issue is probably that you are hitting an error in your toggle handler, what about if you don't remove the toggle click event but comment out the code that is being run (i.e. `this.model.toggle()`)?

Comment: Jack is spot on. The this.model.toggle() was causing other events to fire, re-rendering the Item view, losing events previously delegated to it from MainView. I'll write up a full answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jay B. Martin answered the question.

The problem is that the View calls this.model.toggle();

The toggle() function sets some variables which the MainView is listening for, causing a render() event to fire.

When MainView calls render(), the Item views are in turn removed, rendered and added to the DOM. This loses the bound event to the DOM element using events: {}.

Instead _.bind() or _.bindAll() should have been used to permanently bind the events, regardless of the context / state of the element bound to in the DOM.

---

### Original comment answer:

@Dan0, sorry I'm a little confused about how toggle could be the root of your issue. I think it's a symptom of the context ambiguity created by binding to an implicit DOM element in a nested view. Once toggle is called, the click event loses the context to which it was initially bound (i.e., this.el). The idiomatic way of solving this is to either a) pass an explicit element so that it can rebind on subsequent events, or b) use _.bind or _.bindAll, so that the click event is permanently bound to the itemview as the context changes. – Jay B. Martin Aug 10 at 23:46

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the click event in your item view isn't bound to a specific DOM object. It's possible that listening for a generic click event is overriding Backbone from listening for your specific .item click event. Try adding an ID or class name to your item view click event to remove any ambiguity.

```
var Item = Backbone.View.extend({

  ...

  events: {
    "click .some-class" : "toggle" // This should fix your problem
  },

  ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This doesn't seem to work though. the 'click' event should be bound the object's DOM scope anyway (Which it is). I tested this, and while I can bind it to a child of Item, the child still doesn't fire the MainView click event.

Comment: It's not clear to me which DOM element you're trying to bind Item view's events to. It might help to add an explicit el property. See [View-delegateEvents](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents).

Comment: @JayB.Martin when you just use `'click'` as the event, it is bound directly to the `this.el` where `this` is the view.

Comment: @kalley right, i just realized that he might have included the el property in the portion of his code obfuscated by ellipses. if not, he might be getting the error discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033933/click-event-in-backbone-js-view-do-not-work)

Comment: @nikoshr's jsfiddle code correctly illustrates passing the el property to the nested itemview.

Comment: @Dan0, sorry I'm a little confused about how toggle could be the root of your issue. I _think_ it's a symptom of the context ambiguity created by binding to an implicit DOM element in a nested view. Once toggle is called, the click event loses the context to which it was initially bound (i.e., `this.el`). The idiomatic way of solving this is to either a) pass an explicit element so that it can rebind on subsequent events, or b) use `_.bind` or `_.bindAll`, so that the click event is permanently bound to the itemview as the context changes.